# Adding Guid to a Lookup field

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have written the below function :

```
function openConnectionForm() {
    "use strict";
    var parameters = {};
    var id = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
    id = id.substr(1);
    id = id.slice(0,-1);
    parameters["record1id"] = id;
    alert(id);
        var entityName = "connection";
        var windowOptions = {
            openInNewWindow: true
        };
        Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm(entityName, null, parameters, windowOptions);

}
```

I have a ribbon button "Connect". When I click that button, I want to open Connections form and I want to pre populate the field "record1id" with the guid of the record on which I click the ribbon button.

The form is opening on clicking the ribbon button. But, the field "record1id" is not populated as expected. Some garbage guid is added.

What am I doing wrong?

Update :

I have changed the code to :

```
var id = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
var name = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("fullname").getValue();
alert(id);
alert(name);

var parameters = {};
parameters["record1id"] = id;
parameters["record1idname"] = name;


var entityName = "connection";
var windowOptions = {
    openInNewWindow: true
};
alert("Done");
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm(entityName, null, parameters, windowOptions);
alert("Form Opened");
```

The form is opening.

[image]

But, when I click on the contact, I get this : 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may need to pass three pieces to the parameter. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334375.aspx#BKMK_setValueLookupfields).

#### Example (untested)

```
parameters["record1id"] = [{
    "entityType": "contact",
    "id": id,
    "name": "John Smith"
}]
```

#### Working Code I've used

```
var systemUserObject = [{
    "entityType": "SystemUser"
    , "id": this.currentUser.SystemUserId.Value.id
    , "name": this.currentUser.LastName.Value + ", " + this.currentUser.FirstName.Value
}];

Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ccseq_leaduserid").setValue(systemUserObject);
```

Comment: My entity type is "contact". So, name is contact name?

Comment: Connection form has a lookup field to contact entity. I want to prepopulate this lookup field in connection form.

Comment: @RichaTibrewal Contact name would be the `name` field for the contact.  I've modified code

Comment: I have updated the code in the question. Can you check what's wrong there? I am getting an error : "An error has occurred. 

Try this action again. If the problem continues, check the Microsoft Dynamics 365 Community for solutions or contact your organization's Microsoft Dynamics 365 Administrator. Finally, you can contact Microsoft Support."

Comment: @RichaTibrewal Can you look at the technical details or download a log file?  Seeing the specific error would be helpful

Comment: @RichaTibrewal Perhaps try withou the square brackets? Perhaps my naming convention is a bit off?  I'm not completely sure of my answer because I haven't tried to push data from one form to another, I've only updated Lookups on the current form.  Are there any errors in the dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to populate the `record1id` lookup in Connection entity form when it’s opened from custom ribbon button ‘Connect’. Then you have to mimic the following OOB behavior.

By OOB, when you click `Connect to Another` the Connection form will get **Connected From** lookup prepopulated by current record. Same way when clicking `Connect to Me` will prepopulate both **From** & **To** (`record1id` & `record2id`) with current record & current login user respectively.

[image]

Referring `record1id` from [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/connection?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9#lookup-properties) it’s identical to `regardingobjectid` lookup & [MS says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334375.aspx#Set%20values%20for%20lookup%20fields) it’s not possible to set regarding lookup value.

> You can’t set the values for partylist or regarding lookups.

Comment: I didn’t try this. But you can try - https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/mscrmcustomization/archive/2016/10/28/set-partylist-or-regarding-lookup-when-using-xrm-utility-object

Comment: I am able to set the guid. I think there is another problem. I have updated the question details.

Comment: @RichaTibrewal did you try setting parameters[record1objecttypecode]=2 or contact? I doubt it as it’s a ReadOnly property. Can you paste the url of popup window when you click contact record link, where you get record unavailable error? The url should contain etc=2 or etn=contact, that’s how system knows which entity for it has to open & show the details of record with id=guid from url querystring.